# Get changed page count from a week back

Tags: episerver, episerver-6, episerver-6-r2

I want a widget on the front page of an intranet.
It should display the count of number of pages that have been changed n number of days back.

I tried something like this, but it always returns 0

```
var changeLog = (IChangeLog)ClassFactory.CreateInstance(typeof(IChangeLog), new object[0]);
ChangeLogQueryInfo query = new ChangeLogQueryInfo();
query.From = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
query.Category = new int?(1);
query.Action = (int)ChangeLogPage.ActionType.Publish;
query.MaxRecordsToReturn = 100;
return changeLog.GetChangeCountBackwards(query);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Silly question but is the change log enabled?

Have you tried

```
IList<IChangeLogItem> list = changeLog.GetChanges(query, ReadDirection.Backwards, SortOrder.Descending);
```

Do you get any results?

Also it's worth noting that using the change log is [unsupported](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-6/EPiServer-CMS-60/Change-Log/)

Comment: I'm using the new RecentlyChangedPagesFinder().Find(Count); This uses the changelog under the hood. but that only supports getting the last N number of pages. I want to get a count of all pages changed in the last week.

Comment: Have you looked at the report centre or online centre? There is a report for recently changed pages and a gadget in online center.

You could either use that in itself, or the code within it as a starter.

The template for the report is in the following directory

C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\CMS\[Version]\Application\UI\CMS\Report\Reports

The gadget is MVC, the views are within the following directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\CMS\[Version]\Application\UI\EPiServer\CMS\Views\RecentlyChangedPages 

You will need a disassembler such as reflector to look at the underlying code